# wso2 esb analytics hostname in certificate didn't match: <ip adress> != <localhost>

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When i am integrating wso2 esb and analytics i am getting hostname in certificate didn't match: `<ip adress> != <localhost>`. I tried [this article](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DS200/Troubleshooting+Guide)

but resolved in wso2 esb analytics but wso2 esb is throwing this eroor

**ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712**

**sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed**

Comment: did you create a new cert with IP as the CN?

Comment: yeah I created in analytics with my IP address as first and last name but issue resolved in analytics now esb is throwing above exceptions as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the new public cert to ESB's client trust store. See [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores#CreatingNewKeystores-Step3:Importingcertificatestothetruststore)

Comment: First i got <ip adress> != <localhost> exception in analytics there by importing public certificate, changed the carbon.xml file but analytics is now working fine. But ESB when it connects throwing exceptions as I mentioned

Comment: Did you import the cert to ESB?